# How to implement common method with custom child parameters in PHP abstract class?

Tags: php, oop, abstract

I have an abstract PHP class called 'Car'.

```
abstract class Car
{
    // Extending class must define this method
    abstract protected function getBrand();
    abstract protected function getCars();

    // Common methods
    public function printBrand() {
        print $this->getBrand() . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function printUrl() {
        print $this->getUrl() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

This abstract class implements a function `getCars()`, but this function has basically the same content for each child but with different variables. As there are a couple dozen of children, this method `getCars()` gets redundant. Some children may also need to override the `getCars()` function.

Should I just copy the `getCars()` code to the abstract class and replace the variables with `$this->getVar()`? Or is this not good practice? Thanks in advance.

Edit: If this is the way to go, can some specific children override this abstract function?

Comment: in this case, you may implement this function as a concrete function instead of an abstract function.

Comment: Even if the function has redundant code across a lot of children?

Comment: it's confusing, *`but this function has basically the same content for each child but with different variables`* and *`this method getCars() gets redundant.`* break the function down.

Comment: does this function has the same contents ? or have a contents which get redundant ?

Comment: The code in the function `getCars()` is the same over all the children but takes 4 hardcoded variables which are specific to the child.

Comment: are you sure that you won't to change any of those methods in the future ? if not, you will need to keep them within your children classes.

Comment: Some children need to override them. It's basically my question. Is this the intended use of an abstract class?